# Which site on the SE Network should I use to ask about MSI Afterburner/Riva Tuner?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am looking for the right SE site to ask about MSI Afterburner/[Riva Tuner](https://www.guru3d.com/content-page/rivatuner.html) issues. I'm thinking that [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would probably be a good fit (and preferred by me), however there might be dedicated SE sites that could be better suited.

Which site should I use?

Comment: Somehow two people thought this was a bad question and decided to downvote. I'd love to hear how this is a bad question.

Comment: Dunno but you better not rollback good edits that improves the question. "SE Network" is collection of many sites. "Which SE Network" is wrong, and same for the other small things someone spent time fixing, and you rolled it back. That's both wrong, and not nice towards the one who edited.

Comment: Fixed the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say Super User is a good pick. I would also surmise that it gets more activity than any alternatives, so your question would be more likely to be answered.

Searching for "Riva Tuner" gives a couple of [results](https://superuser.com/search?q=Riva+Tuner).

Comment: As an SU mod - I concur *and* would say there's no other site in the network that'd be a good fit.